# Responsive CSS not working

Tags: css, responsive-design

For this website: http://www.valleylawyermarketing.com/

When you resize this page, the text under the "Testimonial" pic is supposed to float: left, but it doesn't.  I can't understand why.

CSS on non-mobile site:

```
.testimonial_box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    width: 71%;
}
```

CSS for mobile site (not working)

```
.testimonial_box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="testimonial_box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the mobile css in media query specific for it

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.testimonial_box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}  
}
```

you have some invalid characters in your css.css file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
    #portfolio-items .portfolio-grid li {
        width: 240px;
        height: auto;
    }
.testimonial_box {
Â Â Â Â background-color: #fff;
Â Â Â Â color: #000;
Â Â Â Â float: left;
Â Â Â Â padding: 30px 15px;
Â Â Â Â width: 80%;
Â Â Â Â margin-top: 10px;
}  
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I tried plugging that into the CSS stylesheet, didn't work.

Comment: @user3117275:check the invalid characters and remove them and try

Comment: Thank you!  That did it!  Great job. I would have NEVER figured that out. I had cut and paste the code into a text file first.  Wow, something so minor.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have some weird characters in front of each line in your mobile CSS. Get rid of those.

This is what it looks like when I look at your `css.css` file in chrome:

```
.testimonial_box {
Â Â Â Â background-color: #fff;
Â Â Â Â color: #000;
Â Â Â Â float: left;
Â Â Â Â padding: 30px 15px;
Â Â Â Â width: 80%;
Â Â Â Â margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Great catch.  I didn't even know that could be an issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

in mobile css, use `!important` wherever necessary, mentioned below example

```
.testimonial_box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    float: left !important;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    width: 80% !important;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```